# Wix Conditional Statement

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, custom-action

I have the following WIX Condition that doesn't seem to behaving like I expect

```
REMOVE = "ALL" OR USERNAME <> ""
```

I want my custom action to run if it is an uninstall

```
REMOVE = "ALL"
```

Or if the user has entered a username

```
USERNAME <> ""
```

I am performing a "change" installation option and the condition is coming back as false even though I am entering a username?

UPDATE: I am doing this check inside a merge module. The USERNAME property gets set inside the UI which is part of the Main Wix Installer. Don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: Could you try using only `USERNAME` without `<> ""`? like: `REMOVE="ALL" OR USERNAME`.

Comment: It wasn't the fact that my condition was wrong. I discovered that that if I did not run the installer as the Administrator these Properties weren't getting set.